# how to print crystal subreport parameter on main report header

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report where the date parameter is in the sub report. I would like to print the parameter dates in the main report header.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make is a main report parameter and pass it into the subreport as a linked parameter.